# "have done on weekend" vs "had done on weekend"

Tags: present-perfect, past-perfect

Which is the right way to say grammatically?

> 1. If you ***had reviewed*** your lessons on weekend, you ***could*** pass the test now.
> 2. If you ***have reviewed*** your lessons on weekend, you ***can*** pass the test now.

Comment: what tense is 'reviewed'?  what tense should 'have/had' therefore be?

Comment: Please use the correct styling! `> `  for blockquotes...

Comment: What do you know already about tenses in conditionals? Please provide some context about your level of knowledge so that people can post an answer that will help address the specific thing that is confusing you. If you have any idea about which one you think is right, please edit the post to say what your best guess is.

Comment: Yes and further, who said you could use 'on weekend' please?
that might be 'at the weekend(s)' (and possibly in US English 'on the weekend(s) ) but 'on weekend' doesn't work…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If you had reviewed your lessons at the weekend, you could pass the test
>   now.
>
> If you have reviewed your lessons at the weekend, you can pass the test
>   now.

both of these are correct and the difference is how positive they are.

The first one is slightly negative, the sense of "if you had" says that you haven't done this and that means you have no hope.

but the second one is much more positive: if you have done this YOU CAN DO IT.

but you could mix it up and remove the have totally

> If you revised your lessons at the weekend, you can pass the test
>   now.